# AWS Cognito amplify signup method not working

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm trying to create a new user in cognito but the signup method not working for some reason, I also finished configuring the CLI and it working correctly.

here is my code

```
const Auth = require('aws-amplify').Auth;
global.fetch = require('node-fetch');

 Auth.configure({
    Auth: {

    // REQUIRED only for Federated Authentication - Amazon Cognito Identity Pool ID
    identityPoolId: "I already put the identity Pool Id here",

    // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Region
    region: "us-east-2",

    // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito Federated Identity Pool Region 
    // Required only if it's different from Amazon Cognito Region
    identityPoolRegion: "us-east-2",

    // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito User Pool ID
    userPoolId: "I already put the user Pool Id here",

    // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito Web Client ID (26-char alphanumeric string)
    userPoolWebClientId: "I already put the user Pool Web Client Id here",

    // OPTIONAL - Enforce user authentication prior to accessing AWS resources or not
    mandatorySignIn: false,

     // OPTIONAL - Hosted UI configuration
    oauth: {}
    }
});

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const email = event.email;
    const password = event.pass;
    const fullName = event.fName;
    const phone = event.phone;

    Auth.signUp({
        username: email,
        password: password,
        attributes: {
            'email': email,
            'phone_number': phone,
            'name': fullName
        }
    }).then( function (data) {
        console.log("1");
        const response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify(data.user)
        };
        return response;
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log("2");
        const response = {
            statusCode: 520,
            body: JSON.stringify(err)
        };
        return response;
    });   
    console.log("3");
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify("Nothing")
    };
    return response;
}
```

And this is the output:

INFO    3

And this is the response:

{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "\"Nothing\""
}

by the way, I tried amazon-cognito-identity-js but it has the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be triggering the signup properly, but then you do not wait for the response, instead you immediately return a custom response ("Nothing") that has nothing to do with the actual response from signUp.

Try returning the promise that you get from calling the `Auth.signup` function instead, like this.

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const email = event.email;
    const password = event.pass;
    const fullName = event.fName;
    const phone = event.phone;

    // NOTICE! Here is where you return the chained promise resulting
    // from the then(...) and catch(...)
    return Auth.signUp({
        username: email,
        password: password,
        attributes: {
            'email': email,
            'phone_number': phone,
            'name': fullName
        }
    }).then( function (data) {
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify(data.user)
        };
    }).catch(function (err) {
        return {
            statusCode: 520,
            body: JSON.stringify(err)
        };
    });
}
```